# Create dynamic PDF in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, flash

Trying to understand from a high-level how this would be accomplished.

Use case:

- Flash application embedded in HTML used to create Certificates (just an example).
- User enters a bunch of data into a form (Name, Address, What certificate is for, etc.).
- User clicks a button which causes the application to create a Certificate in PDF form, with the form data displayed in a format that I define with a bunch of different images).
- Ideally, Flex could use the browsers functionality to prompt the user with "What would you like to do with this document, 'Download', 'Open'. So it would function just like clicking on a link to a PDF document inside of a web page.

I already have the form and everything, its just a matter of how I create a PDF from that data. Is there a certain function that can take the current screen and create a PDF image of it? Or is there a certain library for creating PDFs? If anyone can point me in the right direction it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a AS3 PDF generator library called AlivePDF and can be found [here](http://alivepdf.bytearray.org/).

Comment: OK, i believe I was over-thinking this issue. I looked at some examples using AlivePDF and we have it working exactly how I described ... and you're right, it was really easy. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

[Purepdf](http://code.google.com/p/purepdf/)
is another actionscript library for creating Pdf file.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. How does Purepdf stack up against AlivePDF?